# Ionic 3 Barcode Scanner Change Title and Cancel Text

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a Ionic project and it use Barcode Scanner. When i click barcode scanner i am seeing Title "Barcode Scanner" and Cancel Text for cancel.
i want to change text title and cancel text. How can i change them ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Post some code and we can help you

Answer (score 0):

i find answear;

```
/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/src/ios/scannerOverlay.xib
```

Open this directory and you can change text in there
“Barcode Scanner” 
“Cancel”

Edited;

```
<string key="IBUITitle">Barcode Scanner</string>    
<string key="IBUITitle">Cancel</string>
```

its codes in there, i have changed but its not working. Why not ?

Comment: Have you found a working solution?